# Error on this Haskell code

Tags: parsing, haskell

```
rango :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
rango (length list) b list = 
rango a b list = if ((list!!a) == (list!!b)) then 0++(rango a b+1 list)
           else(rango2 a list!!b list)++(rango a b+1 list)


rango2 :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
rango2 a b list = if verif((take 2(map(+(a!!2))a)) (take 2(map(-(a!!2))a)) (take 2(b))) then [1]
     else [0]


verif :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Bool
verif a b c = if ((c!!0 < a!!0) && (c!!0 > b!!0) && (c!!1 < a!!1) && (c!!1 > b!!1)) then True
          else False
```

**The Error is: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)**

on this line

```
rango a b list = if ((list!!a) == (list!!b)) then 0++(rango a b+1 list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rango :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
rango (length list) b list =
```

The above line lacks a definition after the `=`. This confuses the compiler in the line below.

Further, `(length list)` is not a valid pattern, as Rhymoid points out.

As a general comment, your code seems to contain several type errors as well. You probably should rethink a bit your approach. Are you sure the type signature of your function is correct? Do you really need as input two lists of integers and a matrix? Is the output intended to be a list of integers?

My advice would be to learn the basics of Haskell first, starting with simpler exercises. If you are trying to write a function to compute the rank of a matrix, that may be too complex at this stage.

Comment: And `length list` is not a valid pattern.

Comment: And 23 more problems... This program makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Mmm okok, and how i can do to get like a parameter, the lenght of the list? e g: i want that the function exit when he reach the last element of the list!?

Comment: @JuanFigueira `f :: [a] -> String; f l = show len where len = length l;` Use `let` or `where` to introduce local bindings without an explicit lambda.

Comment: U're right @chi, im new on Haskell, and the code has too much errors, i need to do too much fixes! ty for your suggestion!